# Swift 3 Переход из потока

Tags: xcode, многопоточность, swift

При выполнении перехода

`self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"main_window", sender: self)`

из потока:

`DispatchQueue(lael: "Auth", attributes: .concurrent)`

возникает ошибка:

> ... 'Reciver ()' has no segue with
>   identifier 'main_window''

Если вызывать переход из класса, то он работает, а из потока нет. Есть какой то способ вызвать это внутри потока?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 3**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil) 
let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "id_SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController 
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate 
appDelegate.window?.root.ViewController!.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**or**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate 
appDelegate.window?.root.ViewController!.performSegue(withIdentifierL "segue_id", sender: nil)
```